# Git newbie, might have messed up my repository

Tags: git, branch

So here is the deal, I'm using git and Bitbucket for my application. I'm using git-flow system for git. So the background is this. I had a release branch called `release/v1.0.2` which had been open for a while (my users are currently beta-testing 1.0.2). Meanwhile beta-testing 1.0.2 I have started implementing on two new features, let's just call them `feature/feature1` and `feature/feature2`.

Today I decided that I was finished with feature1 and feature2 and also the beta-testing for v1.0.2 was finished. So what I did was this (using Atlassian Sourcetree):

1. Finish release v1.0.2 (meaning rebase `release/v1.0.2` into `dev` and merge `release/v1.0.2` to `master` branch, and create a v1.0.2 tag) If you're wondering why I'm using rebase into dev is because I've heard that it's best to use rebase.
2. Finish feature feature1 (rebase `feature/feature1` into `dev`)
3. Finish feature feature2 (rebase `feature/feature2` into `dev`)
4. Create a new release (`release/v.1.0.3`) from `dev`.

***Result***

In the `release/v.1.0.3` there are ALOT of files missing and there are some code present which should have been removed from `feature/feature2`. I really don't understand what went wrong.

What would be the easiest way to revert what I've done and give it another go. But this time hopefully get it done correctly from the beginning (how would I do that considering what I did the first time did not work out)...

EDIT

It seems that when I tried to finish the `feature2` it did not merge it into `dev`. Could the culprit be that when I tried to finish the `feature2` release it had some conflicts which had to be manually solved? At least what I can read out from this log after doing a finish on `feature2`:

ab3473c HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from feature/feature2 to develop 
2f83ac7 HEAD@{6}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/feature/feature2 
2f83ac7 HEAD@{7}: rebase: Update default images

If look at the log after doing a finish on `feature1` it seems to have merged it properly into `dev`:

05bf843 HEAD@{53}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/feature2 
ab3473c HEAD@{54}: merge feature/feature1: Fast-forward 
bf8bdda HEAD@{55}: checkout: moving from feature/feature1 to develop

Comment: After you rebased your two features, did you merge each feature into dev? (it should be just a fast-forward merge)

Comment: @JohnnyZ it might have not merged feature2 into dev, please look at my edit...

Comment: Can you paste a screen shot of what your branches look like in SourceTree?

Comment: (the graph with the pretty lines)

Comment: If you have conflicts it should display an error message somewhere "Finish was aborted due to conflicts during rebase."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `rebase` instead of merge. Rebase rewrites history, it's not what you want. Rebase is espacially *bad* with branches that you've already pushed. Hopefully you have not pushed this mess to BitBucket, but you've pushed everything to BitBucket just *before* creating this mess. In that case:

```
git fetch  # assuming remote origin points to BitBucket
git checkout feature/feature1
git reset --hard origin/feature/feature1
git checkout feature/feature2
git reset --hard origin/feature/feature2
git checkout release/v1.0.2
git reset --hard origin/release/v1.0.2
```

The pre-mess status is now restored.
Create the v1.0.2 release on master.

```
git checkout master
git merge release/v1.0.2
git tag v1.0.2
git push origin master
git push --tags origin
```

Merge you new feature branches and the v1.0.2 fixes to dev, and start the new v1.0.3 RC branch from dev:

```
git checkout dev
git merge feature/feature1
git merge feature/feature2
git merge release/v1.0.2
git checkout -b release/v1.0.3
```

Comment: Why is rebase "bad" ? According to this answer (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/191878/85434) I should use rebase...

Comment: Rebase is good on a strictly private feature branch, which you want to bring up-to-date with upstream.

Comment: Okay, well actually I'm the only developer for this application so maybe it's not so bad then?

Comment: You mentioned rebasing a release branch, which was obviously published, as other people were beta-testing it. That is *BAD*.